# Past perfect or present perfect?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, simple-past

*We didn't go to the party last night because we have had a fever*

Or

*We didn't got to the party last night because we had had a fever*

I know the past perfect describes an completed before a certain moment in the past. Past perfect to express an action whose time isn't given and not definite. But here I don't understand which tense would be correct to use. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

They're both correct, but they mean slightly different things.

It seems to me the best answer would be

> ... because we had a fever.

This says that you had a fever last night, but doesn't say whether you had a fever before last night, or whether you have a fever now. That's all the information you really need to convey.

Both the alternatives work, but carry more information:

> ... because we have had a fever.

This implies that you still have a fever.

> ... because we had had a fever.

This implies that you had a fever before (possibly including) last night, but that you are probably over it by now.

Answer (score -1):

Given the words "last night" I would say "have had a fever".  But if you were talking of a party in the more distant past, it would be "had had".

Comment: But isn't past perfect tense is used to show an action completed before something that happened in the past (simple past tense). If I use had had doesn't it mean their fever was over before going to the party?

Comment: @RichHandsomeGuy Yes.  Now that you have added "last night" I would say "have had" is better.  Without "last night" I was assuming a party longer ago than that - e.g. if you were writing this in a novel.

Comment: Can you elaborate why it's better to use have? Is it because the time of the fever is not specified? I want to understand it clearly so I won't be confused in the future again when I'm making such type of sentences.

Comment: I don't think "had had" could ever be wrong when talking about the past. "Have had" only makes sense if the fever was recent enough to also be relevant in the present.

Comment: Thanks Tony for taking the time to answer my questions. I appreciate it. I have just one more confusion. In my book it says the past perfect tense is used for a certain action which had been completed before another action in the past. So according to the rules if I use had had in the sentence it should mean their fever had been over before they decided not to go to the party. And if I use present perfect it should mean the fever still affects them in the present. So, isn't it better to use the Past continuous with sentence *We didn't go to the party last night because we were having a fever*?

Comment: The past perfect is used to backshift both the present perfect and the simple past. If you have a fever now, and you got it three days ago, you use the present perfect and say *I have had a fever for three days*. So if you had a fever last night, and you got it three days earlier, you would say *I had had a fever for three days*.

Comment: Thank you Peter! I clearly understood what you said. I don't have any doubts now.